# How do I use a browser as a client in python sockets?

Tags: python, client

I tried to search in the internet for this subject, But I didn't found some answers.

If some know how can I use a browser as a client in python sockets it will be very good.

Answer (score 1):

To use the browser as a client to a python (server) socket, you simply need to point it to the right endpoint.

Assuming you are running the browser and the python server on the same machine, and that you're opening port 1234 on the server socket, you simply need to open the `localhost:1234` URL in your browser.

Of course, what happens next is entirely dependent on how you handle the communication in your program. Most browsers will understand plain text put directly on the socket, but you probably want to talk [HTTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol).

It's worth mentioning that using a plain `socket` to communicate with a browser is, at best, uncommon. There may be better solutions, depending on what, exactly, you want to do:

- If you just want to quickly serve a few files from a directory (i.e.: often
  called a "directory listing"), you can use [`SimpleHTTPServer`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/simplehttpserver.html)
- If you're trying to build a website, you should look into a web framework, such as [Django](https://www.djangoproject.com/), [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/) or [CherryPy](http://cherrypy.org/)
- If you want a lower-level highly asynchronous scalable communication, [Tornado](http://www.tornadoweb.org/) is a popular choice

Answer (score 1):

You might want to consider using websockets.  They essentially function like regular TCP sockets, but are initiated with a HTTP handshake, making them suitable for browsers.  They are supported in recent versions of all major browsers.  There are many libraries available that adapt common python webservers to serve websockets as well, for example:

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/gevent-websocket/

if you like gevent.

They also support an SSL layer, which is called using a url starting with "wss://" on the browser side.  More information here:

https://www.websocket.org/